# pip не устанавливает пакеты в окружение

Tags: python, pip, venv

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

активировал окружение, хотел установить requests, а pip просматривает системный репозиторий вместо реп. в виртуальном окружении. И устанавливает все пакеты туда независимо включено ли окружение

окружение создавал командой

```
python -m venv posts
```

Answer (score 1):

Напиши в PowerShell или Cmd

```
cd posts\scripts
.\pip.exe install requests
```